# Spring Data Tool Suite - Bulk Insert of objects

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am developing an API that create a list of Questions , and would like to know check if STS have any native capability that can support bulk insert , or if i have to create a custom query using @Query annotation?

I have refer to this [Spring Data MongoDB support bulk insert/save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685754/spring-data-mongodb-support-bulk-insert-save) , i would like to check if an unique ObjectId still be generated through bulk insert/save?

Sample definition i am expecting , where each question is differentiated with an unique Id.

```
questions": [
    {   
    "id" : "01-QuestionId",
    "type" : "multiple",
    "question" : "What is your Gender?",
    "options" : [
    {
            "key" : "a",
            "value" : "Male"
        },
        {
            "key" : "b",
            "value" : "Female"
        }
    ],
    "survey":{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Test1",
    "description": "First Survey"
    }

    },
    {   
    "id" : "02-QuestionId",
    "type" : "multiple",
    "question" : "What is your income?",
    "options" : [   
        {
            "key" : "a",
            "value" : "1000"
        },
        {
            "key" : "b",
            "value" : "2000"
        }
    ],
    "survey":{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Test1",
    "description": "First Survey"
    }

    }
]
```

Thanks all!
Robin

Answer (score 0):

Found out after deeper research in Spring Data.

We can just use save() or insert() interface from MongoRepository class.

For example

final List savedQuestions = questionRepository.save(questions);